# Stop users committing to git as wrong user

Tags: security, git, authentication

I'm using git and [Codebase](http://www.codebasehq.com/) for a project.

I just did a test and I'm able to commit to the git repository with a different email address and name set which causes it to tag the commit as being by a different user. I pushed this to the repository and it showed up as that user having committed even though it was me.

Is there a way to prevent users from committing or pushing with someone else's user details (effectively so they can't "forge" commits as being from a different user)?

**Edit:**

I assume this authentication would need to happen at the stage of pushing commits to the server since in the local working copy it's simply a repository which the user has full access to, to do whatever they want with. Is this therefore something I should ask [Codebase](http://www.codebasehq.com/) about maybe?

**Edit 2:**

Git config as requested:

(repo/.git/config)

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@codebasehq.com:<redacted company name>/<redacted project name>/test.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Can you post contents of your .git/config?

Comment: What are you using for the server? Plain git, gitosis, gitolite,...?

Comment: The OP is using Codebase, which is similar to GitHub.  It's at the top of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ooops**: While this is a valid technique, it assumes you have effectively full control over the server.  If you're using a hosted solution all bets are off.

You can validate the author name and email in the repository's `update` hook.  You can get both values like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -- refname sha1_old sha1_new
author_name=$(git log --pretty=format:%an $sha1_new)
author_email=$(git log --pretty=format:%ae $sha1_new)
```

The trick, of course, is figuring out whether or not these are valid.  Here's one trick:

You can use the `command=""` option in your ssh configuration to make a wrapper around `git-receive-pack` that maps ssh keys to author information.  For example, something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

GV_AUTHOR_NAME="$1"
GV_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$2"

export GV_AUTHOR_EMAIL GV_AUTHOR_NAME
eval exec $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

And you would use an `authorized_keys` line something like this:

```
command="~/bin/gitvalidator 'Lars Kellogg-Stedman' 'lars@seas.harvard.edu'" ssh-rsa ...
```

The result of all this is that your `update` script would have the environment variables `GV_AUTHOR_NAME` and `GV_AUTHOR_EMAIL` available, and could check these against the commit and exit with an error if they didn't match.

Comment: It is customary to leave a comment if you downvote someone's answer.  That helps folks improve the quality of their answers over time.  If there is something wrong with this answer, please let me know so that I can fix it.  Thanks!

Comment: (...although I suspect this was simply retaliatory.)

Comment: I think I'll ask the guys at Codebase what their position on this is then, thanks :)

Comment: Ok well Codebase say they can't do anything about this as it is common in some organisations for people to push commits by other people. Going to accept this answer anyway as it looks like it would provide a good solution for someone hosting their own central git repository.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry my post got deleted before I submitted my latest update:

You can commit as someone else when you have their credentials.

Just to clarify, the scenario you are asking about is as follows:

Users Foo and Bar can commit to the repo. You want to prevent user Foo from committing to the repo as user Bar.

In this case, user Bar would have to protect their private SSH key, just like they would protect a password. As that is used to authenticate your commit.

Comment: You can set your name and email to anything you want.  It doesn't matter what ssh key you're using (or even if you're using ssh or not).  SSH keys have absolutely nothing to do with the name and email address recorded by git.

Comment: Commits are made locally by git completely independent of the transport used. In a conventional setup, if you are using ssh as a transport, the credentials used to authenticate the user doing the push need not have anything to do with the content of the commits being pushed.

Comment: He's asking in relation to Codebase, which is similar to GitHub.  Looking at the problem in relation to what's actually being asked would be helpful when evaluating answers!

Comment: Codebase (AFAIK) and certainly github aren't special in this regard. Once you are authorized to push to a repository, you can push commits committed and authored by anyone you like.