# Add access to only one git repository via SSH key, not the entire host

Tags: git

on a server, I want to have several git repositories. I want different users (=different SSH keys) to have access to different repositories (think of GitHub).

I know I can add a user's SSH key to `authorized_keys` on the server. But that would give the user access to all repos.

How can I set this up correctly? How does GitHub do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to install a tool for managing remote access to git repositories, such as:

- [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/)
- [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)
- [Gogs](http://gogs.io/)

If you're not willing to use any of those options, you can hack something together by binding keys in your `authorized_keys` file to a specific command (using the `command=` option) that is a wrapper that validates repository access. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8248062/147356) has some ideas that might help you get started.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I made a project for this problem. A git repository manager with virtual authorizations: Custom virtual routes, specific access for each user to specific repositories only:

Features:

- Access to specific repositories for each user.
- Prevent expose original internal paths.
- Prevent access to out storage directories.
- Separate authorization for read and write access.
- Prevent a command execution out of git shell.
- Use multiple users with multiple access with only one ssh account.
- Very lite, only one python script and one json settings, no need a big application with big databases structures.

https://github.com/WHK102/gitman